# force absolute positioned div not to overlap

Tags: css, positioning

I have a *header* bar that is positioned using `position:absolute;` and I cannot seem to get it to **not** overlap my content.

[image]

Here is the html i'm using for my example:

```
<div class="ui-page ui-page-active">
    <div class="ui-header">
        <div class="ui-title ui-title-h1">
            Page Title 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-content">
        <a href="#pg-two">Page Two</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-footer">
        <div class="ui-title ui-title-h3">
            Page Footer 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my css

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.ui-page {
    background-color: #bbb;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.ui-page-inactive {
    display: none;  
}
.ui-page-active {
    display: block; 
}
.ui-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-content {

}
.ui-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 150%;
}
.ui-title-h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

My end goal is to have a header bar always at the top, a footer bar always at the bottom and for the content to fill the centre. The content div does not ***actually*** need to fill 100%, I just don't want it to be blocked by either the header or footer.

Comment: Is the whole thing supposed to fit to exactly the size of the browser window?

Comment: 100% width, 100% min-height | But the height can expand to +100% viewport. This will be viewed on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to have either padding-top or margin-top (I'm not sure which) on .ui-content set to the height of your header, that would push .ui-content down so there isn't overlap.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do that. There is no display property combination that will allow me to do what i'm looking for?

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, what I stated was the easiest way. Another way would be to float all the divs to the left, then the header would stay on top. Another way would be to position the ui-content absolutely, and there are probably a dozen more ways to do it. But I don't know of any magic combination that will keep them from overlapping. What is wrong with a little top padding/margin?

Comment: Nothing really. You know when you get an idea in your head. you want to do something without or with a certain criteria.. but with no real reasoning why ?

Answer (score 0):

If the header and footer are a fixed-height (like, for example "80px") then you can make the content absolute with the top-and-bottom margins (position:absolute;overflow-y:scroll;top:80px;bottom:80px;) and make the header and footer fixed (position:fixed;height:80px;top:0;left:0;right:0;overflow:hidden; for the header and position:fixed;height:80px;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;overflow:hidden; for the footer)

Something like that might work.